# "have brought" vs. "have taken"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Context: suppose I live in a place, say A. At sometime in the past, I travelled to a another place let's say B.

Before going to B, I thought that I am not allowed to take an smart phone with me so I didn't take mine. But when I get there, it turned out that I was wrong and I could take one with me to B. When I reached there and realized it, I said to my self:

> Oh, I could have brought my smart phone here.

Now, suppose that I am in A and I want to describe this past event to a friend. Which one of the following sentences are correct:

> 1 Not until I got there,  did I realize I could have brought my smart phone (there).

> 2 Not until I got there, did I realize I could have taken my smart phone (there).

> 3 It turned out that I could have brought my smart phone (there).

> 4 It turned out that I could have taken my smart phone (there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is *bring here* or *take there*, and applying this rule would suggest that your sentences 1 and 3 are incorrect, while 2 and 4 are correct.

However it is possible to stand at a bar and ask a person sitting at a table "do you want me to bring you a drink". In this case "here" is from the point of view of the person at the table, not the person at the bar.

The sentence "When I arrived (at the office) I realised I could have brought my phone" is correct if you are still at the office when you speak. It can still be used when you are back at home, because the unstated "here" will be understood to mean where you were when you realised, ie at the office. Both your sentences 1 and 3 are correct when understood in this way.

I would usually prefer your sentences 2 and 4 (using *taken*) because they can be understood without the viewpoint shift.